# PGSQL - No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: json, postgresql, stored-procedures, casting

This code gives an error. I have looked similar type questions and couldn't find the answer.

`sum(COALESCE(((rpt.report_target_data::json->>'itemQuantity')::int)::int),0) as itemQuantity,`

**report_target_data** is a json object and 'itemQuantity' is an element of that json. Sometimes that field contains an empty value. So when I try to get the sum it gives an error because postgres cannot get the sum if a column had a empty value. What is the wrong with the above code. It there a way to walk around that matter? Is there a way to calculate sum even if some rows contain empty values?

Here is the error of the above code ->

> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: You're passing `0` as a second argument to `sum()`. You probably meant to pass it to `COALESCE()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. COALESCE will assign a default value for null values. Is there a way to assign a default value for empty string (" ") ?@NickBarnes

Comment: `coalesce(nullif(your_value,''),0)`